Unable to connect using Remmina and wireguard on linux mint
I want to connect to another machine(probably windows server) using wireguard . they have provided a RDP file to connect.
I have installed wireguard and
sudo wg show 
gives me thw right parameters entered in the config file. so wireguard is good
But in Remmina, on importing the rdp file and connecting, i am getting error
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_disconnect) - Disconnect signal received on RemminaProtocolWidget
this is from Remmina debug logs.
Please help me solve this, what could be the issue and how to connect using rdp file from linux mint.

check this answer, hope it helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415498/error-when-trying-to-connect-to-windows-computer-with-remmina

Try to increase the timeout in the advanced settings

